# Wordpress site is very slow after being attacked by malwares

Tags: wordpress, security

I have been developing this [website](http://www.pata.org) and we had to use Gravity Form plugin.

There was a time when it went very vulnerable and the website was attacked (a massive crash occurred to the site) ever since the website has never been normal every again. It is extremely slow to download sometimes there are some error messages `503` We have securely monitoring the website, have the wordpress and every plugin updated to the latest version or even delete the one without the recent updates but it seems not enough because if you access the website now you will feel that it's extremely slow.

Is there anybody who has experienced this kind of attacked? (especially, from when you got attacked via Gravity Form plugin)

I would really appreciate you answer.
Scott

Comment: Did you rebuild the site entirely after the attack? If not, you're probably still compromised.

Comment: No I didn't. There are over thousands of files there. Is there any way I can clean rebuild the site without discarding all of those datas on the website?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by discarding data. I'm referring to nuking all of the files, reinstalling everything (WP, the plugins, and any themes) from clean sources, and restoring a clean backup of the database. "Nuke from orbit" is the only sure way to recover after a site is hacked. It sounds like you did not do this, which will make recovery at this point extremely difficult if not impossible. You should start by downloading the security plugin WordFence; it will help you start looking for problems.

Answer (score 1):

As Ed Cottrell mentioned you must rebuild your site.

1. Make a backup of files and database
2. Write down which plugins you use
3. Delete everything (leave only wp-content/uploads)
4. Install clean WP - it will be best if you use the same version you used
5. Install all the plugins - the data is still in DB, so you won't have configure them again
6. If you bought a theme - just download it again and install it. If someone made it for you - check it for some strange eval or some js files you dont's know. When you are sure it's clean put it back on the server.
7. When everything is done, change user passwords and ftp password.

Use https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/ - it will help to find some nasty code.